# How does `drush features-update` work?

Tags: 7, drush, features

I have made changes to a Feature on a Drupal 7 site.  I want the same feature to be updated in another website. How to do it using the `drush features-update` command? When I run it, it asks to overwrite the previous Feature, but nothing new comes in the Feature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Drush feature-update updates the feature **code** with overwritten settings. So the function is used to export changes to code.

If you want to take those changes to another site, you will have to copy the updated feature to the other site unless they share the same code (and then revert the feature and clear cache (not always needed)).

In code it could look like this

```
$ drush fu feature_module
$ cp -r feature_module ./DIR
$ cd DIR
$ drush fr feature_module
```

Comment: @subhojit777 Update takes the changes from the site and into the feature code, revert is the reversed process of removing (reverting) the custom changes in a site and using those defined in the feature code.

Comment: No. All that feature-update does is update the feature code with customizations of the *existing* components of the feature (E.g. new fields on content type, changed field settings). If you want to add additional components, you need to do it through the UI or by manually updating the .info file of your feature and then run drush fu. drush fu has nothing to do with moving code between multiple sites, search for version control/git if you're looking for that.

Comment: @Berdir ... adding components can be done via the command line with "drush features-export" as explained here http://www.alexweber.com.br/en/articles/drupal-development-boss-using-drush-and-features